# Getting System-Wide Windows 8 Toast Notifications

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, notifications, .net-4.5, windows-8.1

How could I, using C# in either a WinRT (ideal although unlikely) or Legacy app, access previous (and likely missed) Toast Notifications from all applications?

As best as I can tell, there is no easy way to do this (no obvious APIs, understandably so for security reasons, especially for Metro apps) so I'm looking for clever ways to accomplish this. One idea (I don't know if it's possible) is if these are (or can be) logged to an Event Log, the it should be pretty simple.

Ideally, I'd like this to be a Metro app with 8.0 and 8.1 compatibility. However, I doubt that's possible for understandable security reasons. Realistically, doing this is as a Legacy app would be sufficient and probably much easier since I can run that as an administrator.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that when you launch the toast you also write your data using one of the storage APIs.
Have a llok at the options here: http://www.codefoster.com/storage

what I would prefer would be to use HTML5 localStorage so that you can access the information anytime because it never expires. And you can access from another app or even from a web page.

Comment: This doesn't help in any way with getting system-wide toasts, just my own personal ones.

Comment: This allow you to have your application toasts available system-wide.

Comment: I want system-wide toasts available to my application. My entire goal is to write a Toast Persistence application so a user can see all of the toasts that all apps have sent out while they weren't looking and to clear them away on their own schedule instead of Windows' schedule.